# How do I link a CSS stylesheet from another folder below in the directory?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to link into my HTML and it's not working I tried taking off the two periods and that doesn't work either.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="..CSS/file.css">
```

Comment: Describe your folder structure for me. Do you have CSS in the same directory as your HTML file? Is it above? Is it a child of a directory in the same directory as the HTML?

Comment: is this problem on a website or your desk/laptop?

Comment: the HTML file is one directory above the css file so i tried to link it with the two periods. Thing is, it used to work that way. There's no problem as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../CSS/file.css">
```

### More cases:

You can go up directories with `../`

So for each `../` you will go up 1 directory

---

If you are in `/public/files/` you can do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../CSS/file.css">
```

to get into `/public/CSS/`

---

If you need to acces the root it could be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../../file.css">
```

to get into `/`

---

You can also link it from the current script directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="./CSS/file.css">
```

If you are in `/public/files/` it would be `/public/files/CSS/`

---

And last from root to the directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="/public/CSS/file.css">
```

It would be `/public/CSS/` and your file

Comment: IT still won't work, even with the two periods and back slash. Does it help to know that I'm using Sublime Text Editor? It used to work actually.

Comment: If you could post the hiërarchie of your project where the css can be found. If you inspect your code in chrome (networks tab) can it find your style.css ? If not what is the location he is looking for?

Comment: It finds my CSS but only some of it. I know I have stuff like border, background color, etc. but that's not showing up in inspect element

Comment: I've been mistaken. After careful inspection, I've noticed that what is showing in Inspect Element is nowhere close to my CSS
And no I am not sure how I am gonna show you. I'm new here.

Comment: You should make a new topic for it, and mark a question as solved my problem for this particular part. The new question/topic would be about your css and its problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../CSS/file.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to import css files to another css file use below syntax:

```
@import "url or path to file";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../../CSS/file.css">
```

Or use full url :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="://www.yoursite.com/file.css">
```

In full url, :// is instead specify http:// or https://

Comment: To use full you could just do: "/foldersToCss/css/file.css" as starting with a slash points to the root directory.

Comment: Then you can use only // so it supports http and https ;-)