# Why is my external style sheet not working?

Tags: css

This is my html below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> - as you can see I refer to the external style sheet.
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UFT-8">
<meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Natours</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class ="header">
This is some cool text...
</header>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0;
padding:0;}    


</style>
</html>
```

I save the Html file as HTML, and save the CSS file as a CSS file, but after I click to save the external stylesheet as a CSS file, and click save, I go back to the file but its still set as a neutral file, not a CSS file.

-Below is my CSS-
body{background-color:black;}

I've tried multiple times to use the forums, but many people say that I'm using it correctly.

Comment: `link` needs to be a child of `head`.

Comment: Hello :). Just to clarify: does your external css file not get loaded or can't you save a file as css file (.css) on your computer?

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/) before posting. This eliminates any machine-detectable errors, which is a requirement for posting a [mcve] which was expected of you to be included.

Comment: This is the third time now that you are asking about noob sh*t like this … go learn some basics, please.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UFT-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Natours</title>
    <!-- Always include your CSS inside the head tag, you may include it in body too, but head is prefered -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        This is some cool text...
    </header>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did selected selected **All Types(*.*)** for the **Save as Type** dropdown while saving the file.

By default it saves as a ".txt" file. you need to select All Types. 
[image: Save as image]

Besides is your CSS file is in same folder or other folder. If in another folder please check this:
[[How do I link a CSS stylesheet from another folder below in the directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947600/how-do-i-link-a-css-stylesheet-from-another-folder-below-in-the-directory][2])